# finding an apt-get installation

Tags: installation, apt

Warning : totally noob question...

I just started using ubuntu at home, and i love it, but there are some basic stuff that i don't know how to do and is annoying me...

When I install a package using `sudo apt-get install ...` I don't even know where the installed package is. For some packages it doesn't really matter to me, but for some it does...

Example : I just installed vim, and I would like to create a shortcut to vim on my desktop. How would i do this ? How can i find the folder where it was installed and know which executable I need to shortcut ?...

Maybe coming from the world of Windows, I'm not even thinking like a linux user, so feel free to correct me... :)

Answer (score 2):

if you wish to find the directory of the executable `vim`, use `which` command: `which vim`. It will display where the executable is located.

Answer (score 1):

And welcome ;)

To extend [nickanor's answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIBUK.png) you can create a .desktop file to point to vim executable. Just open gEdit with root permissions

```
gksu gedit
```

and paste:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim
GenericName=Vim Editor
Exec=vim
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=IDE;Editor;
```

Then save the file to `/usr/share/applications/` with name `vim.desktop`.
Then you can see `vim` when you search it in the dash:

[image]

Another faster aproach is just to open the terminal (`Ctrl + Alt + T`) and write ´vim filename´ which will open the editor with specified file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

vim is located in /usr/bin/vim. Most executables, that is, scripts that start a program are in /usr/bin or /sbin or /usr/sbin. You can find about anything with:

```
sudo updatedb
locate <whatever>
```

updatedb indexes a database and takes a few moments, so be patient.

I doubt you really want a shortcut to vim, however, since vim requires an argument; that is, a file to create or modify, for example:

```
vim newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend on Ángel Araya's answer. You could run  `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel`  then open  gedit and type

```
 [Desktop Entry] 
Name=New launcher...
Exec=gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new 
Type=Application
```

Then save to the desktop as gnome-launcher.desktop.
Finally you should have a *button* to make a launcher on your desktop.